# Implementation of merger sort in java

Tags: java, sorting

i am implementing an emerge sort on a very integer array of index around 10^5 . I know there is inbuilt sort command available in java but i want to implement on my own. The output array is not sorted please find where i am wrong?
**CODE**

```
public void sort(ArrayList<Integer> finalarray)
        {   
            if(finalarray.size()<2) return ;

            ArrayList<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>();
            int  mid = finalarray.size()/2;
            for(int i=0;i<mid;i++) left.add(finalarray.get(i));
            for(int j=mid;j<finalarray.size();j++) right.add(finalarray.get(j));


            sort(left);
            sort(right);
            int l=0, r=0 , m =0;
            while(l< left.size() && r< right.size())
            {

                  if(left.get(l)> right.get(r))
                  {
                      finalarray.set(m, right.get(r));
                      r++;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      finalarray.set(m, left.get(l));
                      l++;
                  }
                  m++;
            }
            while(l< left.size())
            {
                 finalarray.set(m, left.get(l));
                 l++;
                 m++;

            }
             while(r< right.size())
            {
                 finalarray.set(m, right.get(r));
                 r++;
                 m++;

            }

        }

    }
```

Input : 1
4
5
2
2
5
0
8
2
2

Output: 0
0
1
2
2
2
2
8
2
2

Comment: you could provide a sample output to show where exactly it is wrong, that would help speed up understanding the problem

Comment: @kicker86 the output array is not sorted

Comment: @Singapore Show us an example (small) input and an example wrong output.

Comment: @Singapore use Arrays if you want to learn something

Comment: @Singapore - I would recommend using a debugger. If you have not used it before, now would be a good time to start. :)

Comment: Please check  it i have added the input and output i got !!!

Comment: You miss 2 semicolon (m++).

Comment: add loggers , debug your code. This site is meant to help not solve your issues !

Comment: how come your output is different from input ? 2 zeroes no 5 ? extra 2's

Comment: @Singapore [did you actually test your code?](http://ideone.com/nqjNnS)

Comment: yes  i have test it and i am not getting the sorted output

Comment: @Singapore Take a look at my link please. It shows that everything works fine with the provided input. Are you sure that the code you posted is your actual code?

Comment: @Singapore Also, the output you posted is impossible with the provided input.

Comment: As i am using arraylist is this the reason for bad output

Comment: please help i am stuck here

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a debugger .

You might wanna change your **if** loop to **while** .

```
while (l< left.size())
        {
             finalarray.set(m, left.get(l));
             l++;
             m++;

        }
while (r< right.size())
        {
             finalarray.set(m, right.get(r));
             r++;
             m++;

        }
```

Comment: @Singapore have you re-compiled your code after making the changes ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi below the while loop there should be 2 more while loop in the sort method instead of if.

While (l

currently it is if